# SQL Server : Second maximum value per group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with data as below

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl
(
  ID VARCHAR(20)
  , Desc1 VARCHAR(30)
  , BALANCE_DATE DATE
);

INSERT INTO Tbl (ID, Desc1, BALANCE_DATE)
VALUES ('ID1', 'Desc 1', '10/18/2015')
  , ('ID1', 'Desc 2', '10/19/2015')
  , ('ID1', 'Desc 3', '10/22/2015')
  , ('ID1', 'Desc 4', GETDATE())
  , ('ID2', 'Desc 1', '9/18/2015')
  , ('ID2', 'Desc 2', '9/1/2015')
  , ('ID2', 'Desc 3', '9/28/2015')
  , ('ID2', 'Desc 4', GETDATE());

╔═════╦════════╦════════════════╗
║ ID  ║ Desc1  ║ BALANCE_DATE   ║
╠═════╬════════╬════════════════╣
║ ID1 ║ Desc 1 ║ 10/18/2015     ║
║ ID1 ║ Desc 2 ║ 10/19/2015     ║
║ ID1 ║ Desc 3 ║ 10/22/2015     ║
║ ID1 ║ Desc 4 ║ 11/21/2015     ║
║ ID2 ║ Desc 1 ║ 09/18/2015     ║
║ ID2 ║ Desc 2 ║ 09/01/2015     ║
║ ID2 ║ Desc 3 ║ 09/28/2015     ║
║ ID2 ║ Desc 4 ║ 11/21/2015     ║
╚═════╩════════╩════════════════╝
```

I need to get the latest dated row other than the current date.

Expected Output:

```
╔═════╦════════╦════════════╗
║ ID1 ║ Desc 3 ║ 10/22/2015 ║
║ ID2 ║ Desc 3 ║ 9/28/2015  ║
╚═════╩════════╩════════════╝
```

How to query it?

Comment: Apologies, the values below create table command are the values in the table.

Comment: What if there are multiple rows with the same date? Which one should be chosen?

Comment: @stuartd : Apologies, should have told earlier. The tables contains unique records for the combination of ID and Balance_Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Joe's answer is going to work, I'd strongly suggest using [ranking functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in this case, you won't have to join your table twice and this is a perfect use-case for them. This would be the following query:

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE
(
  ID VARCHAR(20)
  , Desc1 VARCHAR(30)
  , BALANCE_DATE DATE
);


INSERT INTO @Tbl (ID, Desc1, BALANCE_DATE)
VALUES ('ID1', 'Desc 1', '10/18/2015')
  , ('ID1', 'Desc 2', '10/19/2015')
  , ('ID1', 'Desc 3', '10/22/2015')
  , ('ID1', 'Desc 4', GETDATE())
  , ('ID2', 'Desc 1', '9/18/2015')
  , ('ID2', 'Desc 2', '9/1/2015')
  , ('ID2', 'Desc 3', '9/28/2015')
  , ('ID2', 'Desc 4', GETDATE());
  
;WITH CTE(ID, Desc1, BALANCE_DATE, RN)
AS (
  SELECT ID
    , Desc1
    , BALANCE_DATE
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY BALANCE_DATE DESC)
  FROM @Tbl
 )
SELECT T.ID
  , T.Desc1
  , T.BALANCE_DATE
FROM CTE AS T
WHERE T.RN = 2;
```

###Result:

```
╔═════╦════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ ID  ║ Desc1  ║    BALANCE_DATE     ║
╠═════╬════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ ID1 ║ Desc 3 ║ 2015-10-22 00:00:00 ║
║ ID2 ║ Desc 3 ║ 2015-09-28 00:00:00 ║
╚═════╩════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

This query should always pick up row for each id with second highest date.

If you want to test it online, please see constructed query on [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/395989/second-maximun-value-per-group).

###Update

```
INSERT INTO @Tbl (ID, Desc1, BALANCE_DATE)
VALUES ('ID1', 'Desc 1', '10/18/2015')
  , ('ID1', 'Desc 2', '10/19/2015')
  , ('ID1', 'Desc 3', '10/22/2015')
  , ('ID1', 'Desc 4', GETDATE())
  , ('ID2', 'Desc 1', '9/18/2015')
  , ('ID2', 'Desc 2', '9/1/2015')
  , ('ID2', 'Desc 3', '9/28/2015')
  , ('ID2', 'Desc 4', GETDATE())
  , ('ID3', 'Desc 1', '10/18/2015')
  , ('ID3', 'Desc 2', '10/15/2015');

;WITH CTE(ID, Desc1, BALANCE_DATE, RN)
AS (
  SELECT ID
    , Desc1
    , BALANCE_DATE
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY BALANCE_DATE DESC)
  FROM @Tbl
  WHERE BALANCE_DATE < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
 )
SELECT T.ID
  , T.Desc1
  , T.BALANCE_DATE
FROM CTE AS T
WHERE T.RN = 1;
```

###Result:

```
╔═════╦════════╦══════════════╗
║ ID  ║ Desc1  ║ BALANCE_DATE ║
╠═════╬════════╬══════════════╣
║ ID1 ║ Desc 3 ║ 2015-10-22   ║
║ ID2 ║ Desc 3 ║ 2015-09-28   ║
║ ID3 ║ Desc 1 ║ 2015-10-18   ║
╚═════╩════════╩══════════════╝
```

Comment: Thank you for the query. This works perfect with the given data. However if i have records like ID3,Desc1,15-Oct-15 and ID3,Desc2,18-Oct-15. I need to get the last dated row other than the current date, which in this case is record dated with 18-Oct-15. Seems your query returns 15-Oct-15. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: @Ramu Do you mean you have to exclude current date from the list, right?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. Yes, just observed seems its not providing results as expected if we have just one record.

Comment: @Ramu I'll update my answer right now. Check it. It should also bring back record if there's just one row for that Id.

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH cteMaxDateNotCurrent AS (
    SELECT ID, MAX(BALANCE_DATE) AS MaxDate
        FROM tbl
        WHERE BALANCE_DATE <> CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
        GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT mdnc.ID, t.Desc1, mdnc.MaxDate
    FROM cteMaxDateNotCurrent mdnc
        INNER JOIN tbl t
            ON mdnc.ID = t.ID
                AND mdnc.MaxDate = t.BALANCE_DATE;
```

Comment: Thank you Joe. Your solution works for me as well. Wish i could mark your answer also as accepted solution. Thank you again for your time and effort